# mvn clean command error

Tags: java, maven

I am new the maven, and after several years of programming, mainly in Ruby and JS, I am back to Java.

I just start to play around with Maven, And when I run `mvn clean` I get the following error (I am running this on OS X El-Capitan 10.11.6):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for commons-lang:>commons-lang:jar with value '>commons-lang' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 15, column 25 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The project com.chen:HelloWorld:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/Users/chenn/Development/HelloWorld/pom.xml) has 1 error 
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for commons-lang:>commons-lang:jar with value '>commons-lang' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 15, column 25 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

The POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>com.chen</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I've been trying to find the answer but struggled on the way.

Comment: `<artifactId>>commons-lang</artifactId>`
this line is producing the error.Change it to:
`<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>`

Comment: The error clearly says `'>commons-lang' does not match a valid id pattern. @ line 15, column 25`. Remove the extra `>` and it should be good.

Comment: No way I wrote a question for a typo! Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

`<artifactId>**>**commons-lang</artifactId>`  you have a > too much in this line

Answer (score 0):

Extra `>` in `artifactId` is causing you problems.